# Customization of pushbutton in qt (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I am trying to customize a **pushbutton** in such a way that when the **pushbutton** is clicked and held the process will be executed once released the process is stopped ?

Since I am new to qt any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the button property "autoRepeat" to true.
then after that play with the initial delay and the frequency for the signal emission...

[image]

you have to connect the signal/slots of course...

and after that you can call the process repeatedly

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "HelloWorld";
}
```

> "Debug@2020.03.09 08:33:25.897 CET - HelloWorld"
>
> "Debug@2020.03.09 08:33:26.918 CET - HelloWorld"
>
> "Debug@2020.03.09 08:33:27.918 CET - HelloWorld"
>
> "Debug@2020.03.09 08:33:28.918 CET - HelloWorld"
>
> "Debug@2020.03.09 08:33:29.149 CET - HelloWorld"

Comment: Thanks for the reply !!   Your method works for the case where the process is a short one like printing "hello world", but in my case i am trying to control a processBar so the function is when i press and hold the pushbutton, processBar should change and when i release the button the processBar should stop at that point itself.                                                                                                                        I tried using pushButton_pressed but once i press the pushButton processbar starts running even after i release it the progessBar continues to run.

Comment: then you should had explained that in the description of your question

Answer (score 1):

Check the `signals` of `QPushButton` like triggered, pressed released... With these, you can handle your execution of the process!